# AWS CLI to filter images based on tags

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ami

I want to get AMI's which are not having a `specific tag` using AWS CLI. I do not know how to use not included filter.

Tried this BUT getting error.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --profile prod --owners asfhjaf --filter "Name=name,Values=UAT" "Name=tag-key,Values!=Delete" --query 'Images[*].[ImageId,CreationDate]'
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options that you can try is to use `--query` parameter along with `--fitlers`.

- First filter key Name
- Then query where `not sometag`

```
aws ec2 describe-images  --owners asfhjaf  --filters Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query 'Images[].Tags[?Value != `sometagvalue`]'
```

output

```
[
    [
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "demo"
        }
    ],
    [],
]
```

or to remove the empty array

```
aws ec2 describe-images  --owners asfhjaf  --filters Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query 'Images[].Tags[?Value != `sometagvalue`]' | jq '[ .[] | select(length > 0) ]'
```

To print **Image ID and creation Date**

```
aws ec2 describe-images  --owners abcd  --filters Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query 'Images[].{Tags:Tags[?Value != `sensu`],ImageId:ImageId,CreationDate:CreationDate}' | jq '[ .[].Tags | select(length > 0) ]'
```

Comment: tried this:
aws ec2 describe-images --profile prod --owners dsfjbfba --filter "Name=name,Values=UAT" --query 'Images[].Tags[?Key!=`Remove`]' | jq '[ .[] | select(length > 0) ]'  
How to i get ImageID here? I want list of Image IDs only so that i can remove them later. I was trying --output text but it is not working with jq

Comment: I have multiple servers each with daily AMI backup. So i want to delete old AMI`s which doesnot have the Tag:Remove. That`s why in filter i specified the server name.

Comment: Answer udpated. you can try now

Comment: I dont think not equals work. I tried the below query but still getting complete list irrespective of the tag value. aws ec2 describe-images --owners abshdgd --filter "Name=name,Values=UAT1" "Name=tag-key,Values=DeleteOn" --query 'Images[].{Tags:Tags[?Values != `never`],ImageId:ImageId,CreationDate:CreationDate}' --output text